# Handling more than 1024 sockets?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, select

I'm working on a MMO game server project and I have a problem. That's select() method's limit. I want to handle more than 1024 socket I/O with a single thread. I want to make this with single thread because I've tried to make a multi-thread handling system. That system creates 3 thread (for example in 4 cores processor; 1 is main, 3 is select() handlers) that handles select() method but there is an other problem again, now our limit is gone to 3072 (1024 * 3) and that isn't a solution! After that idea, I want to make a non-blocking socket system, with this system I've called 2 different select method in 1 single thread like this; "select() select()". They returns in order and I can handle them in order. But there is an other problem I think. If I want to implement a thread like "while(true){ select() select()}" and select() methods (non-blocking) retuns, I'll overload CPU like a empty "while(true)" block. If I want to make a select() timeout, I can't handle bottom select() in realtime. Now I can't make a algorithm for that. Can anybody help me about this?

**NOTE:** I don't want to use poll-epoll-wsapoll etc. ***(poll cannot handle microseconds, it isn't fast as select!)*** and libevent like 3rd party libraries (I want to make my own!)

**FINALLY SOLUTION (I think):** I don't need to handle nanoseconds for a I/O operation because there is no sense to handle it. Poll is a good way to handle more than 1024 socket I/O. I'll research something for understanding MMO systems. And the last one is I'll make some tests and I'll try somethings before I ask a question :) Thanks!

***EDIT:** I'm new in this Q&A platform. Can you tell me what's wrong with my question after giving a negative point? :)*

Comment: "I want to make my own!" FYI, epoll requires kernel support. You would need to write a kernel module. IOW, just use epoll.

Comment: Also, this is probably an XY question. "because of something" tell us what that something is and maybe we can help solving that problem instead, as epoll is really the way to go.

Comment: @rightfold no, I want to use "select()" like method. I've added reasons for why I don't want to use ~poll.

Comment: The amount of time you waste implementing your own version of `epoll` or `select` would be better spent learning how to properly use them and concentrating on your MMO.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious How can I learn? I can't find a good book/article for that.

Comment: Seriously, use `epoll`. It's made for scenarios like this. Short of writing your kernel module (and even then...), you're not going to beat its performance.

Comment: "select vs poll" - the linked message is probably 10+ years old. don't make decisions based on that. use epoll/kqueue/poll/libevent.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Oh, sorry about that!

Comment: @PiLaWYeR You're on one of _the best_ programming related websites since the beginning of the entire universe. Search SO for questions and answers related to epoll and start absorbing as much information as you can. Once you've done that revisit what you're trying to do and start putting together what you've learned. Write a few test programs outside of your MMO, run some tests, search SO for problems you encounter, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: You are silly to believe `select()` actually support microsecond precision. Just because the language is implemented that way doesnt mean it does. This level of time precision require special hardware and shit.

Comment: @PiLaWYeR: If you're at all concerned about portability, you should use something like `libev` or `libevent` or even `libuv`. I personally suggest `libev`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I've posted and I got -3 points for that. What can I do after that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `select` is fundamentally wrong with this many (thousands) of connections. While `select` is usually faster when you have only a very small number of sockets (maybe tens,) it scales horribly to several thousand and more. Everywhere that I know of, `select` slows down linearly with the number of connections (it's even worse than that, but I wouldn't go into the details.)

Even `poll` doesn't do much better than `select` at scaling to thousands of connections. It doesn't have `select`'s (low) limit on the number of file descriptors you can poll, but it still scales linearly with the number of connections.

What you really should use are platform-specific facilities like `epoll` and `kqueue`. They scale extremely better (usually *O(1)*,) but obviously they aren't portable.

I seriously suggest that you consider something like **[libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html)** that is a portable, highly-tested and a thin wrapper around platform-specific facilities and services.

This is because platform-specific methods (e.g. `select`, `poll`, `epoll`, `kqueue`, I/O completion ports, event ports, etc.) are different form each other and none of them is available on more than one or two platforms, or their limits and the details of their behaviors differ slightly. These facilities might even change from one version of an OS to the next (e.g. `epoll` on Linux 2.6.9, IIRC.)

Even if you are not concerned with portability or future-proofing your code, such a library can provide you with more functionality and a nicer interface.

Two more libraries you can try are **[libevent](http://libevent.org/)** (a little larger and slower, but more features) and **[libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv)** (if you need Windows portability.)

Comment: Yes, I'll try. (As I said 2 more times)

Comment: @PiLaWYeR he's just adding it as an answer because comments aren't really the place for solutions. So even though you may have heard it already, it's a good idea for yzt to do so, this way future users can know it's a potential solution.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-BernardPellerin. That's exactly what I should and am doing. I know this question already has an accepted answer, but someone searching for the subject of this question might arrive here and I feel the currently accepted answer doesn't provide enough information or any solutions. That's why I'm adding my 2 cents.

Answer (score 4):

Given the requirements you have set, your problem has no solution.

- The normal way to overcome `select()`'s limit of `FD_SETSIZZE` (1024) file descriptors is to use `poll()` (or even better alternatives epoll and kqueue) but you've rejected that option.
- Otherwise, you could always overcome the problem by calling `select()` multiple times in parallel in different threads with different sets of file descriptors... but you've rejected that option too.

I don't believe there can really be any other solution!

Perhaps you should explain why both the `poll()` et al option and the thread option are not suitable. Your requirements seem like artificial limitations without justification.

Comment: And the moral is that you can't solve problems if you avoid solutions. \*Control+W\*

Comment: poll method isn't fast as select. select can handle a operation in microseconds but poll can't. That is my reason to "why I don't want to use poll".

Comment: LOL darn you [rightfold](http://stackoverflow.com/users/142019/rightfold) I hit that key combo! ;)

Comment: You are doing I/O and complaining about a microsecond. That combination makes no sense.

Comment: @PiLaWYeR Are you *really* sure the millisecond-resolution timeout for `poll()` is a problem for you? I really doubt that. Due to scheduling vagueries, you just can't depend on those kinds of timers being that precise anyway!

Comment: @Celada Oh, I think you're right. There is no sense to handle microseconds for our I/O operation :)

Comment: @PiLaWYeR The only reason you would need that kind of resolution is if you are polling for data in your main thread. From what you have described you should be handling all incoming data in a separate thread anyway.

Comment: @PiLaWYeR: "poll method isn't fast as select" - oh really? have you actually measured it? you would be surprised...

Comment: @PiLaWYeR: Also, `select` might accept the timeout value in nanoseconds (it's nanoseconds, and not microseconds) but it absolutely wouldn't and couldn't keep that amount of precision.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Yes, I'll make a data I/O listener thread for polling I/O. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @PiLaWYeR: And the OS-specific mechanisms for polling (epoll, kqueue, completion ports, etc.) will always be faster than `select`. Because most likely, `select` is implemented using them under the hood. (Well, not always, but `select` is always farther from the OS and hardware than platform-specific methods.) So if you don't need to be portable and you need performance, definitely use your platform services.

Comment: @yzt Anyway I can port my project to other systems with changing some methods as poll(). Am I right?

Comment: @PiLaWYeR: Well, in theory yes. But the semantics and usage of poll/epoll/kqueue/inotify/completion ports/etc. are not exactly (or even remotely) the same across OSes. They sometimes even differ from one version of the OS to the next. I suggest you use something like `libev` if that suits your requirements (functionality, license, etc.)

Comment: @yzt Yes, `libev` is suitable for me I think. (without license because I'll share my own network library)